# How to make bundler work again for non root users ? (after mistakenly using it with root)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am new to Rails , I ran bundler as root by mistake & now it is not working correctly. I tried to use `gem uninstall bundler` then `gem install bundler` but still it is not fixed.
How to make bundler work again for non root users (after mistakenly using it with root)?

Note: 
I have installed and use rbenv, but after installing some gems on the system directly

The error that happens is that bundle doctor shows correct missing gems but sudo bundle doctor doesn't as shown below

```
~/my_ruby_projects/myblog3$ bundle doctor
The latest bundler is 1.16.0.pre.1, but you are currently running 1.15.4.
To update, run `gem install bundler --pre`
The following gems are missing
 * execjs (2.7.0)
 * coffee-script (2.4.1)
 * coffee-rails (4.2.2)
 * font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.2)
 * temple (0.8.0)
```

using `sudo`
    ~/my_ruby_projects/myblog3$ sudo bundle doctor
    The latest bundler is 1.16.0.pre.1, but you are currently running 1.15.4.
    To update, run `gem install bundler --pre`
    The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
    No issues found with the installed bundle

Thanks for your help

update:
I knew that bundle with sudo is correct since it gave the real gems that rails tells me they are missing , if I use bundle install without sudo it gives error as below (even if change it to chmod 777)

```
~/my_ruby_projects/myblog3$ bundle install
The latest bundler is 1.16.0.pre.1, but you are currently running 1.15.4.
To update, run `gem install bundler --pre`
There was an error while trying to write to `/home/usrname/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions`. It is likely that you
need to grant write permissions for that path.
```

for sudo bundle install it says all is installed but then rails throws error that I need to install gems (**which bundle doctor gave without sudo**)

```
/my_ruby_projects/myblog3$ sudo bundle install
The latest bundler is 1.16.0.pre.1, but you are currently running 1.15.4.
To update, run `gem install bundler --pre`
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Using rake 12.0.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
# many other gems
Using redis-rails 5.0.2
Using rails_admin 1.2.0
Bundle complete! 30 Gemfile dependencies, 98 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Update 2:
`rails s` was giving error that gem files are missing
but `**sudo** rails s` worked without errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try changing the owner and setting the correct permissions for your `~/.bundle`.

Try:

```
sudo chown -R <youruser> ~/.bundle
```

Followed by:

```
sudo chmod -R 655 ~/.bundle
```

Comment: why that 2nd cmd ? the 1st I think re-gave my user the ownership of the dir , but why specify the it as 655 permissions ?
bundle worked without sudo after the 1st cmd , but still `rails s` is not working , is there anything to resolve missing for rails ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: rails s gave the following without sudo:

`Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
FATAL: Listen error: unable to monitor directories for changes.
Visit https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers for info on how to fix this.
Exiting`
the github link is unclear to me , answer is not marked

Comment: -1: Second command seems outright dangerous.  `655` would remove `x` bit for owner.  And `-R` changes directories and files to the same even though they're generally different.  Why go changing permissions when ownership is the issue.